# avoid duplicates once upload csv into bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I used the google documentation sample code to upload CSV files (in the cloud storage) into bigquery.
I end up having lots of duplicate rows as there are lots of duplicates in the CSV files. How I can check and avoid uploading duplicates?

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

There are two options in my mind:

1. There is a line to add to the above code to cleverly avoid uploading rows that already exist in bigquery. Is there such a thing?
2. Using cloud function, cloud scheduler, and pub/sub to check the bigquery tables every 24 hours and if there are any duplicates, remove them (simple SQL query removes duplicates) This solution needs a bit of extra work on setting up cloud function, scheduler and pub/sub. The volume of data is several hundreds of Gbytes so it will be costly and not very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid and remove duplicates with `BigQuery`, you can use [merge queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement)

A merge query allows to :

- Update the element if exists
- Insert the element if doesn't exists

Example :

```sql
MERGE dataset.Inventory T
USING dataset.NewArrivals S
ON T.product = S.product
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (product, quantity) VALUES(product, quantity)
```

To be able to develop this use case, you can use the following steps :

- Use a staging table with the same structure as the final table (no need to keep data for each execution in the staging table)
- Your Python script firstly `truncate` the staging table
- Load the file to the staging table
- Execute a merge query to insert or update the element if it exists
- The merge query is applied between the staging and final tables

Example with your script :

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
staging_table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

# Truncate staging table
truncate_query = client.query(
    f"TRUNCATE TABLE `$staging_table_id`"
)

truncate_results = truncate_query.result()

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states.csv"

# Load CSV file to staging file
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, staging_table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))

# Execute merge query between staging and final table.
# Replace this query by your merge query.
merge_query = """
    MERGE dataset.Inventory T
    USING dataset.NewArrivals S
      ON T.product = S.product
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE SET quantity = T.quantity + S.quantity
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (product, quantity) VALUES(product, quantity)
"""

merge_results = merge_query.result()
```

You can also check this article [remove duplicate bq batch pipeline](https://medium.com/google-cloud/remove-duplicates-in-bigquery-batch-pipeline-with-airflow-and-dataflow-2e7da5772c4d) I written, that shows and explains a deduplication use case with `merge query`.

Comment: Hi Mazlum, sorry what does the second to last line mean? merge_query = ....

Comment: Hi Sana, it corresponds to the `merge` query. Replace it by your `merge` query.

Comment: @Sana have you tested the solution ? Keep us informed please.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way of avoiding duplication by having a spreadsheet with your data being imported.

Open your CSV file in a spreadsheet. Then, set the spreadsheet into [Federated Data Source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-sources#:%7E:text=Federated%20queries%20use%20the%20BigQuery,converted%20to%20GoogleSQL%20data%20types.) in Bigquery. Afterwards, you can use [DML (Data manipulated language)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#insert_statement) to load the data into existing table. You can use an `INSERT INTO` statement with `NOT IN` syntax to only load new rows into the table.

Here is the sample query:

```
INSERT INTO `existing.table` (sample_row, sample_data)
SELECT *
FROM `imported.table` 
WHERE sample_row NOT IN (
  SELECT sample_row 
  FROM `exiting.table`
)
```

Note: Do not run **multiple** INSERT INTO statements at the same time as you can possibly have duplicates in the table.

Comment: Thanks @poala, would the solution work even if each file contains millions of rows? CSV files are quiet heavy and billions of rows of data are getting uploaded